# Is VR component in UPBGE technical possible?

Tags: vr

I had try using my Windows Mixed Reality (WMR) headset with UPBGE 0.3 VR scene inspection. Very impressed. I wonder if there will be a VR python component (similar to the first person player) implemented for game development in the near future. If not, is it possible technically to develop this component?

Comment: Please clarify. Are you asking if it's possible on a technical level, or are you asking if somebody could make this feature?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Perhaps I shall ask if it is possible to enable the VR feature in game development using the Python component of UPBGE. Also, I would like to know if the developer team of UPBGE is planning to enable VR game development.

Answer (score -1):

It is actually possible to develop interactive content in VR inside UPBGE, you can take a look at https://www.patreon.com/upbge_vr

Comment: Thanks for the posts. This is not a regular forum, according to site rules [links to answers are not answers](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2382) if the link goes missing your answer becomes an empty shell without content. Answers should be substantial and stand on their own without relying on external data like links, videos or images. Instead of having users go through external links, either transcribe essential parts of the process here, linking the source, or posts these in the comments section instead.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/158135)

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos, thanks for the feedback, I'm a bit confused on how it could be a correct answer, since I've read again the question and the question seems to be if it is possible or not, so the answer should be a yes or not. Thanks in advance for your guidance.
I want to modify my answer to make it a good answer.

Comment: We tend to reject questions that are requests for resources, or can be answered with a link only. In this case it is fine as is, but maybe you could flesh it out a bit more, list the features of UPBGE VR, or shortly describe the required workflow, maybe add a few [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), illustrating the results.